# Schedule a price change on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, pricing, schedule

I'm trying to find a way to set prices on specific products to change on a specific date.

I know about Catalog Price Rules, but they tend to be more for promotions over a specific period and group of products.

In this case, the site owner sometimes has spare time and knows about upcoming price changes from distributors. So he'd like to use this time to go into individual products' admin page and program this change in advance.

From what I can gather, this is native in Magento 2 commerce, but I was wondering if there was a solution for the open source version? Extension or otherwise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Import Product functionality to perform the change you need.
See [https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9dWk.png) to run the Product Import

I attach a screenshot of the file that I have used on my machine; I have today altered the price for 2 skus and applied some date range for which I wanted the price change to apply.

[image]

Comment: That's a special price though, with a range. I'm assuming I can't change the normal price with a start date?

Comment: In my last screenshot, I set a date being the same in both fields (2022-08-18 00:00:00
) and the frontend shows the special price as expected once the indexes have run

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice that. Perfect! thanks.